# debug email sent in checkout

Tags: magento-1.9, order-email

I want to stop magento sending new order email in some cases.

I want to know from the community how to debug and backtrace the function that really send the order email confirmation email.

I've this event :

```
<sales_order_place_after>
                <observers>
                    <xx_yy_Model_sales_observer>
                        <type>singleton</type>
                        <class>xx_yy_Model_Sales_Observer</class>
                        <method>save_order</method>
                    </xx_yy_Model_sales_observer>
                </observers>
            </sales_order_place_after>
```

And in my save_order function i do this :

```
try{
            $order->setEmailSent(1);
            $order->setStatus("holded");
            $order->save();
        }
        catch(exception $e){
            Mage::log('Non inoltra ordine', 1,'orders.log');
            Mage::log($e->getMessage(),1,'orders.log');
        }
```

But i still receive the new email order.
I'm trying to debug core_email_template_mailer and core_email_template but seems that the email is not sent from there.

any help could be appreciated!!

Answer (score 2):

I think you can try to create one more Observer method for event sales_order_place_before
and move

```
$order->setEmailSent(1);
```

to that new Observer method

Answer (score 1):

Magento does **not** use events to send emails for order confirmation.

The email is sent on order save, specifically in the method
`sendNewOrderEmail()` which is defined in `/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order.php` (assuming that there is not custom module that modify it).

There is a setting in the backend: system -> config > sales emails where you can disable them.

If you want another condition I would write a custom module to extend `Mage_Sales_Model_Order` and add my custom check there in an overwrite of `sendNewOrderEmail()`.